# In notepad++, regular expression or pattern to delete string between quote marks longer than a certain length

Tags: regex, string, pattern-matching, notepad++, quotes

In notepad++, I need a regular expression or pattern to delete a string between quote marks longer than a certain length (say 50).  Please provide a template regular expression that can be used in the "replace all" to eliminate strings, within actual quote mark characters, longer than a certain length.

Comment: Can you add the question?

Comment: please explicate what you want added, I edited for better grammar and for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do:

- Find what: `"[^"]{50,}"`
- Replace with: `NOTHING`